# Headphone mic not getting detected in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, microphone, headphones

My headphones mic is not getting detected in my ubuntu. I have tried different solutions but nothing worked.[image: pulseaudio output]
[image]

Alsamixer-micboost is set to 0. I tried increasing it but if I open it again it is still 0.

I tried different headphones and both audio and mic worked in my ubuntu.
[image]
[image]

I am not understanding why the problem is specific to my headphones. I have tested my headphone mic in Windows OS, it works perfectly fine, so there is no hardware issue.
Someone, please help!!
Thank you

Comment: Is it wireless?

Comment: Wired + Wireless. Also, I am not able to connect it via Bluetooth in ubuntu